# Can I play audio on my Apple Homepod using Airplay from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, airplay

Pretty much as the question. I've got an apple homepod and no other speakers. Is there some way I can use the homepod as an audio destination?

Comment: Related, idk if identical - https://askubuntu.com/questions/833436/airplay-mirroring-from-ubuntu-16-04-to-apple-tv